# Tensor product of a chain complex and a cochain complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

While studying the homology slant product I came across this difficulty.

According to my reference (exercise sheet from my professor), given two chain complexes $A$ and $B$ the slant pairing is defined as

$$ \begin{align}/ \colon \text{Hom}(A\otimes B, R)\otimes B &\to \text{Hom}(A,R) \\
\gamma \otimes b &\mapsto \gamma / b \end{align}$$

where $(\gamma / b)(a):=\gamma(a\otimes b)$.

I don't know much homological algebra, so there may be something I am missing here. But the left factor of the tensor product on the source should be a cochain complex while the right factor is a chain complex. So my question is:

> Does it make sense to tensor a cochain and a chain complex? If so, how is the boundary map defined?

I guess that the objects are the same as for the tensor product of chain complexes, but I couldn't figure out what the boundary map was. I also couldn't find anything about this in the bunch of places where I searched.

Comment: Hey, Pedro, a few clarifying questions: I assume that $R$ is a commutative ring and all complexes involved are complexes of $R$-modules, yes? By "cochain complex" do you mean a chain complex whose differential has degree 1? And can you clarify what you mean by left and right factors in the source? (i.e., which complex do you suspect should be the cochain complex?)